# ¿Cómo podría encontrar todas las palabras que estén entre caracteres "$"?

Tags: java, regex

Tengo una cadena en la cual debo remplazar los valores que están entre **$**, por lo que, debo encontrar estas diferentes variable, si alguien sabe qué expresión regular puedo usar se lo agradezco.

Ejemplo de la cadena

```
filaTabla = "<tr>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$FechaCorte$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$TipoContrato$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$NumeroObligacion$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$EstadoObligacion$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$TipoEntidad$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$NombreEntidad$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$Ciudad$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$Sucursal$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$FechaApertura$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$ValorInicial$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$DiasCartera$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$FechaPermanencia$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                    <td>$ChequesDevueltos$</td>\r\n"
                        + "                </tr>\r\n";
```

Comment: No necesitas una regex para ello. Basta con manipular la cadena, por ejemplo: `const result = filaTabla.split('$').filter((e, i) => i % 2 === 0).join('');`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras en java, cómo lo podría aplicar?

Comment: Vale, pues no has puesto Java como etiqueta y dado que muestras una tabla HTML, asumí Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Esta expresión regular reconoce cualquier cosa entre "$"

```
\$([^\$]+)\$
```

- `\$` calza con un signo "$".
- `[^\$]` calza con cualquier cosa que no sea "$".
- Al encerrar lo anterior entre paréntesis, tenemos un *grupo de captura* que te dará el contenido entre "$$".